Can't get my Clear-Content script to work in Powershell
I have no prior experience with any scripting, so to me this script seems logical. I grabbed the lines off the internet and I feel like I'm missing alot. The script I'm trying to make is supposed to clear the files in these paths. I also need to clear all users except one specific user. Which I don't know any command for.
I've tried this script which I am able to run but it doesn't actually remove the file content.
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp" -File | Clear-Content
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Windows\ccmcache" -File | Clear-Content
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Windows\Temp" -File | Clear-Content
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\All Users" -File | Clear-Content 


Are you getting any errors, like Access denied ? Are you running powershell as administrator ?

I'm assuming you want to discover all files under each folder recursively? If so, use Get-ChildItem ... -Recurse

I'm not getting any errors, when I run the script as an admin the script is run but the folders retain all their content.

Looks like you want to delete the files in the folders, in that case use Remove-Item. Clear-Content is for removing whatever is written in a file:  Deletes the contents of an item, but does not delete the item.
